# Read content of repeating sections with apache POI

Tags: ms-word, apache-poi

I Have a word document with a repeating section, containing other content controls.
In java project, I have a function that gets all sdts (content controls) from a word document in apache POI, in a List List. 
When I inspect my repeating section in that list, I can get the text inside all content controls (inside my repeating section) but is apears as a long paragraph instead of other sdt nodes.
Is there a way to inspect content of repeating section sdt with Apache POI ? I can't find anything about it in the doc

function that gets all sdts
private static List

```
extractSDTsFromBodyElements(List<IBodyElement> elements) {
        List<AbstractXWPFSDT> sdts = new ArrayList<AbstractXWPFSDT>();
        for (IBodyElement e : elements) {
            if (e instanceof XWPFSDT) {
                XWPFSDT sdt = (XWPFSDT) e;
                sdts.add(sdt);
            } else if (e instanceof XWPFParagraph) {

                XWPFParagraph p = (XWPFParagraph) e;
                for (IRunElement e2 : p.getIRuns()) {
                    if (e2 instanceof XWPFSDT) {
                        XWPFSDT sdt = (XWPFSDT) e2;
                        sdts.add(sdt);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return sdts;
    }
```

Comment: It is a basic rule of human communication that one shows at least any kind of reaction if one asked a question and someone tries helping and answers that question. Simply not reacting looks very ungrateful for the one who had tried helping.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to answer, I will test the code you give next time I work on this project, thanks for your answer I will fedd back when I test the code

Answer (score 1):

The `XWPF` part of `apache poi` is rudimentary until now and highly in development. In [XWPFSDT](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFSDT.html) is this mentioned also: "Experimental class to offer rudimentary read-only processing of of StructuredDocumentTags/ContentControl". So until now your code only gets the surrounding `XWPFSDT` of the repeating content control but not the inner controls. One could have seen that by having some debugging outputs in the code. See my `System.out.println(...)`.

So to really get all `XWPFSDT`s we must go other ways using the underlaying `XML`directly.

Lets have a complete example.

Look at this `Word`document:

[image]

As you see there is a single control to input the group name, then a repeating content control around three controls to input name, amount and date and then a single control to input the employee. All controls which shall be read have titles set. So whether the title is set, is the criterion whether a control is important for reading or not.

The following code now can read all controls and their content:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.*;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlCursor;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

public class ReadWordForm {

/*
 private static List<AbstractXWPFSDT> extractSDTsFromBodyElements(List<IBodyElement> elements) {
  List<AbstractXWPFSDT> sdts = new ArrayList<AbstractXWPFSDT>();
  for (IBodyElement e : elements) {
   if (e instanceof XWPFSDT) {
    XWPFSDT sdt = (XWPFSDT) e;
System.out.println("block: " + sdt);
    sdts.add(sdt);
   } else if (e instanceof XWPFParagraph) {
    XWPFParagraph p = (XWPFParagraph) e;
    for (IRunElement e2 : p.getIRuns()) {
     if (e2 instanceof XWPFSDT) {
      XWPFSDT sdt = (XWPFSDT) e2;
System.out.println("inline: " + sdt);
      sdts.add(sdt);
     }
    }
   }
  }
  return sdts;
 }
*/

 private static List<XWPFSDT> extractSDTsFromBody(XWPFDocument document) {
  XWPFSDT sdt;
  XmlCursor xmlcursor = document.getDocument().getBody().newCursor();
  QName qnameSdt = new QName("http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main", "sdt", "w");
  List<XWPFSDT> allsdts = new ArrayList<XWPFSDT>();
  while (xmlcursor.hasNextToken()) {
   XmlCursor.TokenType tokentype = xmlcursor.toNextToken();
   if (tokentype.isStart()) {
    if (qnameSdt.equals(xmlcursor.getName())) {
     if (xmlcursor.getObject() instanceof CTSdtRun) {
      sdt = new XWPFSDT((CTSdtRun)xmlcursor.getObject(), document); 
//System.out.println("inline: " + sdt);
      allsdts.add(sdt);
     } else if (xmlcursor.getObject() instanceof CTSdtBlock) {
      sdt = new XWPFSDT((CTSdtBlock)xmlcursor.getObject(), document); 
//System.out.println("block: " + sdt);
      allsdts.add(sdt);
     }
    } 
   }
  }
  return allsdts;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("WordDataCollectingForm.docx"));

/*
  List<IBodyElement> bodyelements = document.getBodyElements();
  List<AbstractXWPFSDT> sdts = extractSDTsFromBodyElements(bodyelements);
*/

  List<XWPFSDT> allsdts = extractSDTsFromBody(document);

  for (XWPFSDT sdt : allsdts) {
//System.out.println(sdt);
   String title = sdt.getTitle();
   String content = sdt.getContent().getText();
   if (!(title == null) && !(title.isEmpty())) {
    System.out.println(title + ": " + content);
   } else {
    System.out.println("====sdt without title====");
   }
  }

  document.close();
 }
}
```